# return to a part of my script?

Tags: python, function, input, return

can i make a function like this :

```
def again ():
   again = input ( "want to input the word again ?  yes =1 no =2 ")
   if again == 1:
        func_input_word()
   else:
        return keuzemaken
```

Comment: First, what are you trying to do? Second Where is mij input_word?

Comment: the user choose an option ( option 1) and he have to input a word that is longer than 6 lettres , if the word is not longer than 6 , it have to return and ask again for the input_word. thats what i want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I gues this code will do what you want:

```
def func_input_word():
    input_word = ""
    while len(input_word) < 6:
        input_word = input("Input a 6 letter word: ")
        if len(input_word) < 6:
            print("Too small, try again!")
        else:
            return input_word
def option(my_choose):  #function named: make choose ( choice )
    if my_choose == 1:
        input_word = func_input_word()
    else:
        ....
```

Comment: If you're using python 2.x, use raw_input instead.

Comment: no it is a python 3 script , but can i mail you or something else if i need some more help ?

Comment: if i do the some you do , i get a syntax eror because i haven't a if in my other fuction ??

Comment: Ok.. I'm going to edit it. But I tested it and it gave no error.

Comment: no this part is okey , but if i call this , it gaves me an error , i will edit it in my question the part i have call

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
def option(my_choose):  #function named: make choose ( choice )
   if my_choose == 1:
       while len(input_word) < 6:
          input_word = input( "type het gekozen 6 letterig woord in : ") #input for word
          if len(input_word) < 6:
             print ("to short, try again ")
          else:
             break
    else:
    ....
```